# Держать все индексы SphinxSearch в памяти

Tags: sphinx, sphinxsearch

Как заставить searchd держать все индексы в памяти?

На сколько я знаю - максимально можно только 2ГБ. Суммарно мои индексы весят 10ГБ (если считать по размеру индексных файлов sphinx)

Answer (score 0):

> Как заставить searchd держать все индексы в памяти?

Держать все индексы в памяти - очевидно "mlock". Sphinx умеет mlock для атрибутов и словарей (.spa и .spi), но не умеет другие файлы индексов (doclists, hitlists).

Manticore Search (форк сфинкса) умеет и это и позволяет гибче настроить что и как должно кэшироваться в памяти - https://manual.manticoresearch.com/Creating_an_index/Local_indexes/Plain_and_real-time_index_settings#Accessing-index-files , так что если это необходимо, то боюсь, что единственный вариант - миграция на Manticore.